# Docker Desktop Windows 10, but do not work with my second wsl2 ubuntu distro

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, distro

I have already a Windows 10 and Docker-Desktop working good, and I work my docker proyects from my wsl2 ubuntu 22.04 without any problem, but:
I decide to instal my second wsl2 ubuntu 20.04 distro, and do not work with my docker like my other distro does.
[This is the message that ubuntu shows me when I try to run "docker run -p 6543:6543 --name redis --rm redis:latest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXKep.png)

Docket tell me that I need to activate the integration with Wsl2 in the settings, but I allready have checked this option, and not work in my second distro.

I want the second distro (ubuntu20) works in the same way that my first distro (ubuntu22) does when I use docker-desktop windows 10